# How can I list Entry Types of a single Section?

Tags: templating, craft3, sections, entry-type

The following outputs all sections and their entry types, but I'm struggling to work out how I output only the entry types from the "blog" section.

```
{% for section in craft.app.sections.allSections() %}
  <h2>{{ section.name }}</h2>

  <ul>
    {% for type in section.getEntryTypes() %}
      <li>{{ type.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I thought this would work

```
{% for type in craft.entries.section('blog').getEntryTypes() %}
  <p>{{ type.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But I've hit a wall because `getEntryTypes()` is an unknown method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close – this should work:

```
{% set blogSection = craft.app.sections.getSectionByHandle('blog') %}
{% set blogSectionEntryTypes = blogSection.getEntryTypes() %}

{% for entryType in blogSectionEntryTypes %}
    <p>{{ entryType.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The reason why `craft.entries.section('blog').getEntryTypes()` didn't work is that `craft.entries` will actually create an [ElementQuery](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/element-queries/), which is used to query for elements (e.g. entries).

When you use `craft.app.sections` or `craft.app.getSections()` (it doesn't really matter which variant you use, although the latter is a micro-optimisation in terms of performance) you're interacting with the [Sections service](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-sections.html), which is what you need to use to work with sections and their entry types directly, rather than entries.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and for the explanation! I'll read up some more on how Craft works, particularly the parts you've mentioned.

Comment: How can the resulting list of entry types be sorted? I'm having no luck in Craft 4 using the `|sort` filter on these things.